# mmap memory backed by other memory?

Tags: c, linux, mmap, virtual-memory

I'm not sure if this question makes sense, but let's say I have a pointer to some memory:

```
char *mem;
size_t len;
```

Is it possible to somehow map the contents of `mem` to another address as a read-only mapping? i.e. I want to obtain a pointer `mem2` such that `mem2 != mem` and accessing `mem2[i]` actually reads `mem[i]` (without doing a copy).

My ultimate goal would be to take non-contiguous chunks of memory and make them appear to be contiguous by mapping them next to each other.

One approach I considered is to use `fmemopen` and then `mmap`, but there's no file descriptor associated with the result of `fmemopen`.

Comment: I'm not sure that there is any good way to map a second view of existing memory, but one thing you can do is to `mmap` the same file (or shared memory segment, or memfd?) at two different addresses.

Comment: Do you have control over the first page? Are you also mapping the first page beforehand, or do you just want to create another page which should "mirror" one that already exists (i.e. one that is already mapped at a known address)?

Comment: The first region is dynamically allocated memory, initially from malloc, and sometimes grows via realloc. In this case I do have control over how it gets created, but I'd also be interested in supporting arbitrary regions where I don't know how they got created.

Comment: Realloc is a problem, since it can move the block.  You'd have to redo your mapping, and even then, its offset within a page might move, so all your pointers within the alias block have to be recomputed, and your "contiguous" blocks might now have a gap between them.

Comment: I suppose you know that even if this can be done (and I don't know how), you would at best get page granularity?  Unless all your existing chunks are in multiples of pages, you have little hope of getting them to end up contiguous.

Comment: The alias region would be short-lived and computed on demand. I don't need to support realloc while the alias is being used

Comment: @IsmailBadawi see my updated answer.

Comment: It would seem natural to try doing this by mmap'ing `/proc/self/mem`, but IIRC that file does not support mmap.  Which is too bad since that would also be a convenience for debuggers, as a more efficient alternative to ptrace peek and poking.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### General case - no control over first mapping

#### `/proc/[PID]/pagemap` + `/dev/mem`

The only way I can think of making this work *without any copying* is by manually opening and checking [`/proc/[PID]/pagemap`](https://manned.org/procfs.5) to get the Page Frame Number of the physical page corresponding to the page you want to "alias", and then opening and mapping [`/dev/mem`](https://manned.org/mem.4) at the corresponding offset. While this would work in theory, it would require root privileges, and is most likely *not* possible on any reasonable Linux distribution since the kernel is usually configured with `CONFIG_STRICT_DEVMEM=y`, which restricts the usage of `/dev/mem`. For example, on x86 it disallows reading system RAM from `/dev/mem`  and only allows reading memory-mapped PCI regions. Furthermore, note that in order for this to work the page you want to "alias" needs to be locked to keep it in RAM.

In any case, here's an example of how this would work *if* you were able/willing to do this (I am assuming x86 64bit here):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

/* Get the physical address of an existing virtual memory page and map it. */

int main(void) {
    FILE *fp;
    char *endp;
    unsigned long addr, info, physaddr, val;
    long off;
    int fd;
    void *mem;
    void *orig_mem;

    // Suppose that this is the existing page you want to "alias"
    orig_mem = mmap(NULL, 0x1000, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_PRIVATE, -1, 0);
    if (orig_mem == MAP_FAILED) {
        perror("mmap orig_mem failed");
        return 1;
    }

    // Write a dummy value just for testing
    *(unsigned long *)orig_mem = 0x1122334455667788UL;

    // Lock the page to prevent it from being swapped out
    if (mlock(orig_mem, 0x1000)) {
        perror("mlock orig_mem failed");
        return 1;
    }

    fp = fopen("/proc/self/pagemap", "rb");
    if (!fp) {
        perror("Failed to open \"/proc/self/pagemap\"");
        return 1;
    }

    addr = (unsigned long)orig_mem;
    off  = addr / 0x1000 * 8;

    if (fseek(fp, off, SEEK_SET)) {
        perror("fseek failed");
        return 1;
    }

    // Get its information from /proc/self/pagemap
    if (fread(&info, sizeof(info), 1, fp) != 1) {
        perror("fread failed");
        return 1;
    }

    physaddr = (info & ((1UL << 55) - 1)) << 12;

    printf("Value: %016lx\n", info);
    printf("Physical address: 0x%016lx\n", physaddr);

    // Ensure page is in RAM, should be true since it was mlock'd
    if (!(info & (1UL << 63))) {
        fputs("Page is not in RAM? Strange! Aborting.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }

    fd = open("/dev/mem", O_RDONLY);
    if (fd == -1) {
        perror("open(\"/dev/mem\") failed");
        return 1;
    }

    mem = mmap(NULL, 0x1000, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, fd, physaddr);
    if (mem == MAP_FAILED) {
        perror("Failed to mmap \"/dev/mem\"");
        return 1;
    }

    // Now `mem` is effecively referring to the same physical page that
    // `orig_mem` refers to.

    // Try reading 8 bytes (note: this will just return 0 if
    // CONFIG_STRICT_DEVMEM=y).
    val = *(unsigned long *)mem;

    printf("Read 8 bytes at physaddr 0x%016lx: %016lx\n", physaddr, val);

    return 0;
}
```

#### `userfaultfd(2)`

Other than what I described above, AFAIK there isn't a way to do what you want from userspace without copying. I.E. there is not a way to simply tell the kernel "map this second virtual addresses to the same memory of an existing one". You can however register an userspace handler for page faults through the [`userfaultfd(2)`](https://manned.org/userfaultfd.2) syscall and [`ioctl_userfaultfd(2)`](https://manned.org/ioctl_userfaultfd.2), and I think this is overall your best shot.

The whole mechanism is similar to what the kernel would do with a real memory page, only that the faults are handled by a user-defined userspace handler thread. This is still pretty much an actual copy, but is atomic to the faulting thread and gives you more control. It could potentially also perform better in general since the copying is controlled by you and can therefore be done only *if/when* needed (i.e. at the first read fault), while in the case of a normal `mmap` + copy you *always* do the copying regardless if the page will ever be accessed later or not.

There is a pretty good example program in the manual page for `userfaultfd(2)` which I linked above, so I'm not going to copy-paste it here. It deals with one or more pages and should give you an idea about the whole API.

### Simpler case - control over the first mapping

In the case you *do* have control over the first mapping which you want to "alias", then you can simply create a shared mapping. What you are looking for is [`memfd_create(2)`](https://manned.org/memfd_create.2). You can use it to create an anonymous file which can then be `mmap`ed multiple times with different permissions.

Here's a simple example:

```c
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main(void) {
        int memfd;
        void *mem_ro, *mem_rw;

        // Create a memfd
        memfd = memfd_create("something", 0);
        if (memfd == -1) {
                perror("memfd_create failed");
                return 1;
        }

        // Give the file a size, otherwise reading/writing will fail
        if (ftruncate(memfd, 0x1000) == -1) {
                perror("ftruncate failed");
                return 1;
        }

        // Map the fd as read only and private
        mem_ro = mmap(NULL, 0x1000, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, memfd, 0);
        if (mem_ro == MAP_FAILED) {
                perror("mmap failed");
                return 1;
        }

        // Map the fd as read/write and shared (shared is needed if we want
        // write operations to be propagated to the other mappings)
        mem_rw = mmap(NULL, 0x1000, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, memfd, 0);
        if (mem_rw == MAP_FAILED) {
                perror("mmap failed");
                return 1;
        }

        printf("ro mapping @ %p\n", mem_ro);
        printf("rw mapping @ %p\n", mem_rw);

        // This write can now be read from both mem_ro and mem_rw
        *(char *)mem_rw = 123;

        // Test reading
        printf("read from ro mapping: %d\n", *(char *)mem_ro);
        printf("read from rw mapping: %d\n", *(char *)mem_rw);

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: My understanding is that the first mapping of the memory is set up outside the asker's control, but `memfd_create` only works if you can do both mappings yourself.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica hmm, good point. If that's the case then `memfd_create` is of no use here. Let me ask OP in a comment.

Comment: In the first case, you'll have to `mlock` the region in question, so that the page isn't swapped out.

Comment: @NateEldredge indeed, thanks, I'll add that to the answer. You would also have to check the bits read from `pagemap` before trying to map `/dev/mem` to make sure that the page is not *already* swapped out.

Comment: Well, if you `mlock` it first, hopefully that shouldn't be possible.

Comment: @NateEldredge yeah I'm assuming OP has no control over the first mapping in that scenario.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli: You can `mlock` memory that is already allocated.  So there's no reason they can't `mlock` the original region before starting.

Comment: @NateEldredge right... I just did not have the opportunity from my program since I was operating on process' virtual address. I've now re-written it so it's clearer.

Comment: Thanks, there's a lot of good info here. I'll do some prototyping and see where it leads